# How to select starting offset in Pykafka simpleconsumer?

Tags: python, apache-kafka, consumer, pykafka

In my kafka cluster single partition topic i have a simple consumer processing all incoming messages, in case of error about data processed i want to reprocess in the same order all message from a certain offset (not the beginning) to fix the inconsistency and keep the original ordered sequence of message from kafka.

Is there a way to do it in with Pykafka? i'm not figuring it out

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to call [`reset_offsets()`](http://pykafka.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/simpleconsumer.html#pykafka.simpleconsumer.SimpleConsumer.reset_offsets). For example:

```
consumer = topic.get_simple_consumer(consumer_group="example")
partition_offset_pairs = [(p, get_offset_for_partition(p)) for p in consumer.partitions.itervalues()]
# because we passed in a consumer_group the new offsets will be saved in Kafka
consumer.reset_offsets(partition_offsets=partition_offset_pairs)
```

(where `get_offset_for_partition()` is a function you define). Or for a single-partition topic:

```
# read from offset 123456
consumer = topic.get_simple_consumer()
partition = topic.partitions[0]
consumer.reset_offsets([(partition, 123456)])
```

The same `reset_offsets()` method is also available on `BalancedConsumer` & `ManagedBalanceConsumer` classes too.

Note that as part of Kafka's design, messages are only guaranteed in-order for each topic partition independently.